# Why can't I add toolbars in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I have some problems with VS 2013, when I'm editing reports (SSRS). Every time I open reporting services project it starts without Report Data (I have to open it with Ctrl + Alt +D) but I also can't add any toolbar. If I right click on toolbar area and select for instance "Formatting" nothing happens. In menu "Formatting" is checked, but I cannot see it anywhere.

Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: maybe your toolbar is full so you can't see the formatting. have you tried to check this area? http://prntscr.com/8w7aaz it might be hidden so you can see it. For opening the report services without 'report data' it also happens to me. I just do 'CTRL + ALT+ D' or View > Report Data.

Comment: Yes it was hidden. But it didn't show shortcuts to the other toolbars as it is shown in your printscreen. I had to move first toolbar somewhere else and after that other toolbars appeared. Strange... Thanks!

Comment: I have a lot checked in my view>toolbars that's why.. :) i'll add this as answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mybe your toolbar is full so you can't see the formatting. Have you tried to check this area? `prntscr.com/8w7aaz` it might be hidden so you can see it. For opening the report services without 'report data' it also happens to me. I just do 'CTRL + ALT+ D' or View > Report Data.